Puppeteer Missing Dependencies?
On Windows I'm running using Node v18.19.1. To install initially I ran npm i puppeteer.
I'm having some trouble getting my project to run locally after installing puppeteer. I am running version 22.11.2 and when I try to start my project I receive the following error.
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                         friendly-errors 7:51:09 PM

These dependencies were not found:                                                                                                                                                                              friendly-errors 7:51:10 PM
                                                                                                                                                                                                                friendly-errors 7:51:10 PM
* puppeteer-core/internal/node/PuppeteerNode.js in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer.js                                                                                                      friendly-errors 7:51:10 PM
* puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer.js                                                                                                          friendly-errors 7:51:10 PM
                                                                                                                                                                                                                friendly-errors 7:51:10 PM
To install them, you can run: npm install --save puppeteer-core/internal/node/PuppeteerNode.js puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js  

I followed the instructions and ran npm install --save puppeteer-core/internal/node/PuppeteerNode.js puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js but then I receive the following error.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\TiremBareno-Sosna\Development\EduceACCServices\front-end-v2\puppeteer-core\internal\node\PuppeteerNode.js/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\TiremBareno-Sosna\Development\EduceACCServices\front-end-v2\puppeteer-core\internal\node\PuppeteerNode.js\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\TiremBareno-Sosna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-20T23_55_15_828Z-debug-0.log


How'd you install Puppeteer to begin with and what platform are you on? npm i puppeteer should install all deps. I've never had to run anything like npm install --save puppeteer-core/internal/node/PuppeteerNode.js puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js in years of using Puppeteer on Windows and Ubuntu.

Using Windows and the project is  using Node v18.19.1. To install initially I ran npm i puppeteer.

I'm not sure how to reproduce the problem since this works for me out of the box with the same setup. Is npm i puppeteer the command that's failing, or node your-pupp-script.js the thing that's failing? Node 18 is probably still supported, but is starting to get a bit old, so you might try v22, or installing an older version of Puppeteer around v19 or v20 just to see what happens.

No prob, updated the ticket description. npm i puppeteer works fine from what I can tell. When I try npm run build I get the 2 missing dependencies error.

I don't think you need to run npm run build, just npm i puppeteer then node your-pupp-script. I also don't recall having run npm run build. Are you cloning a repo with existing code in it, or writing a script from scratch? If you're cloning a repo with that command in it, I'd provide a link to it, since that might be the problem. Or try running a simple Puppeteer hello world script standalone and see if it works like that.

Cloning a repo with existing code. I run npm run build to run the project locally so I can try to get puppeteer working. I'm using it to try to create PDFs but before I get there the build can't finish before erroring out.

Can you share a link to the repo? npm run build is specific to that repo, not Puppeteer in general, so it's unclear what it's actually doing. Did you confirm that Puppeteer works on your system with a separate hello world? Create a separate folder, run npm init -y; npm i puppeteer then paste in the Puppeteer starter code from the npm package into a file called hello-puppeteer.mjs and see if it works with node hello-puppeteer.

I don't think I can share a link to the repo because I don't have the permissions, this is actually for a work project :). npm run build is actually doing cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server if that's any help.
Good call on trying to see if Puppeteer works on my system with a separate project, will test now.

That pretty much just runs node index but with nodemon to restart it when the source code changes, and some env adjustment--none of that should be relevant to Puppeteer. If the repo is private, I would try to extract and isolate a minimal failing example out of it that doesn't have any protected information. Just pull the relevant Puppeteer build portions necessary to trigger the issue, without any distractions. That seems like the best chance of getting to the bottom of it. But if the standalone hello world fails, there's your minimal failing code--probably a system or environment issue.

If hello world standalone works, then the problem is somewhere between that and your larger failing example--introduce or strip out parts until isolated.
